# Updating of project with root as source causes "Path must include project and resource name" error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

We have many Java projects in Eclipse with a file structure like this:

```
+ project
     + libs
     + scripts
     + inputdata
```

`libs` and `scripts` are source folders, `inputdata` is a resource folder.

We want to transfer all projects to Maven maintaining the old file structure.
I have created a Maven project using the m2e Eclipse plugin. In the pom.xml I have changed `<sourceDirectory>` to the root of the project:

```
<build>    
    <directory>target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>.</sourceDirectory>
...
```

Updating project via right-click on Project -> Maven -> Update project causes a "Path must include project and resource name" error.

But `mvn verify` and `mvn package` pass successfully.

How do I make Eclipse update successfully if I want to have the source directory be the project root?